# Why are my GA4 dimensions not populating?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

We are struggling to migrate our custom UA events to GA4, due to the custom parameters not populating the dimensions appropriately. Events that we call directly from the application (i.e. via the code below) seem to be working ok.

```
gtag("event", "Click", {
                "debug_mode": true,
                "event_category": "Documents",
                "event_label": userId + " - " + href,
                "transport_type": "beacon",               
            })
```

However, events tracked via the GA4 data API (second code block) seem to be coming in ok via Realtime reports, but do not cascade down to the dimensions even after multiple days of waiting.

```
private JSONObject buildParameter(String downloadUrl, long loggedInUser) {
                JSONObject payload = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
                payload.put("client_id", PropsUtil.get("client.id"));
                payload.put("non_personalized_ads", "false");

                JSONArray parametersArray = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray();
                JSONObject parametersObject =JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();

                parametersObject.put("name", "Documents");
                parametersArray.put(parametersObject);

                JSONObject params = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
                params.put("ea", "Click");
                params.put("el", downloadUrl);
                params.put("uid", String.valueOf(loggedInUser));
                parametersObject.put("params", params);

                payload.put("events", parametersArray);

                return payload;

            }
```

We have tested both on-page events, as well as those from the API, but despite both showing in realtime events correctly, only the on-page show up as expected. Screenshots of custom dimensions and parameters below.

[Custom Dimension configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB3LZ.png)

[Custom parameters being displayed under dimension label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0OQk.png)

[Exploration showing not set for dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxVrS.png)